# Remove github remote from sub-folders

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm having this issue where I was using Git for version control. So , I'm having a single folder inside my local repo . Then I pushed it to Github. Everything was fine , today I added a new folder on the same level as the first one (but this one is cloned from another repo on Github).

Structure :

```
    MyProject         
    |---- FrontEnd (Initial Folder)
    |---- Backend (Cloend from another repo)
```

When I try to push it to github I'm getting that arrow icon on the folder.
After I've done some research , I think it's because it's linked to another Github repo.
How can I delete everything related to Git for the 2 folder and push it to another new repository on Github .?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to delete everything to do with git in your second folder / repository, just delete the `.git` folder in your local repository.

However, I would encourage you to make a final commit within that repository and  then rename `.git` to something else so that if you make a mistake and change your mind, you can just rename it back to `.git` and carry on from that last commit.